# Find the infimum value of a functional.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Consider the functional

$$F(u)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha}|u'(x)|^pdx,\ \ \ u\in W^{1,p}(0,1)$$
where $\alpha\ge 0$ and $1<p<\infty$.

Given $a<b$, find the value of 
$$\inf\{F(u): u\in W^{1,p}(0,1), u(0)=a, u(1)=b\}$$

Can any one help me with this problem ?